# Error starting Visual Studio 2017 - Error loading configuration file...IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis

This is not really a show stopper, but it is annoying. I recent switched from IIS Express to plain old IIS. Now when I start the debugger in Visual Studio I get the following error (my co-workers have had it for a long time, so it is not just me):

[image]

After you hit "OK" everything still debugs successfully. I have read a lot of articles that seem to suggest this is a privileges, but I have messed with privileges in the associated directories without being able to get rid of this. Any suggestions welcome.

I can show the contents of the config file at the lines specified, but I don't think that it the real issue.

**Update**

For those with the inability to see images clearly:

"The following error occured while getting connection string information from the configuration file." An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\Users\me\Documents\myapp.web\myapp.Web\Web.config line 126)

Comment: Please post the error information as text rather than an image. The content is all text, and images aren't necessary to convey textual information. Often images are not readable by users behind corporate proxies or using mobile devices. Also, text in images is not searchable content.

Comment: Unfortunately that error message cannot be grabbed as text. But I will type it out a bit later.

Comment: You'd better show some or all lines from `web.config`, as usually we don't have any line like that in it. Why do you need the Azure bits here (unless your team do host the web app on Azure)?

Comment: We host on Azure. Do you want to see the line where it errors out? Obviously I can't show all of it for security reasons

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation or solution? I'm encountering something very similar.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a very similar error dialog, and [opened an issue in the ConfigBuilders GitHub repository](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/issues/129). According to Stephen Molloy from the team, this is a known issue with no good workaround other than to install `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Base.dll` and `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.[Azure|Environment|etc.].dll` in a "findable" location, such as the GAC or the Visual Studio installation directories.